# AngularJS run method call to Cordova 3.4 navigator.globalization gets undefined

Tags: angularjs, cordova, globalization, navigator

I'm struggling here trying to detect the device language setting on startup. I'm using AngularJS and Cordova 3.4. Inside the AngularJs run method I call a service that calls navigator.globalization.getPreferredLanguage().

The problem is that navigator.globalization is undefined during the angularjs startup. I'm waiting for the deviceready event using angular promises. The globalization plugin starts to work on the second click on the app, so I guess it's a timing issue. The Geolocation plugin works fine on startup so I don't understand why this is happening.

AngularJS run method

```
angular.module('guiariumHtml5App', [
  'ngCookies',
  'ngResource',
  'ngSanitize',
  'ngRoute',
  'ngAnimate',
  'ui.bootstrap',
  'google-maps',
  'pascalprecht.translate'
])
  .run(function($log, GlobalizationService) {
    $log.info("App run");
    GlobalizationService.getPreferredLanguage();
  });
```

GlobalizationService.js

```
    'use strict';

    angular.module('guiariumHtml5App')
  .factory('GlobalizationService', function($log, CordovaService) {

    var serviceInstance = {
      getPreferredLanguage: function() {
        $log.info('getPreferredLanguage');
        CordovaService.navigator().then(function(navigator) {
          var onSuccess = function(language) {
            setTimeout(function() {
              alert(language.value);
            }, 0);

            //$translate.uses(language.value);
          };

          var onError = function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
              alert("Error getting language");
            }, 0);
          };
          $log.info(navigator);
          $log.info(navigator.language);
          $log.info(navigator.userLanguage);
          $log.info(navigator.globalization);

          // Navigator.globalization is undefined
          navigator.globalization.getPreferredLanguage(onSuccess, onError);
        });
      }
    };

    return serviceInstance;
  });
```

CordovaService.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('guiariumHtml5App')
  .factory('CordovaService', function($q, $log) {
    var d = $q.defer();
    if(window.navigator) {
      $log.info('navigator found on window');
      d.resolve(window.navigator);
    }
    else {
      document.addEventListener('deviceready', function(evt) {
        $log.info('deviceready');
        d.resolve(navigator);
      });
    }

    return {
      navigator: function() {
        return d.promise;
      }
    };
  });
```

Anyone sees a timing issue here?